# Adding a dynamic view inside an <li ng-repeat>

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.3 and ui-router (which I'm pretty new to) for a project and have a set of design elements I'm not clear on how to tackle.    All the ui-router examples and tutorials that I've been able to find show the classic left sidebar list of objects that when you click on an item in the list, a shared ui-view on the right is loaded with relevant detailed content.   I understand that approach but the designers I'm working with for a project have a design where a list of users is vertical full page width and clicking on a user needs to expand underneath a view that has a graph and other meta data about the user which will require an API call to fill the content in.

structure of HTML is basically

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="name in names"> 
   <span>{{name}}</span>
   <div>Graph/content goes here on click of name span above</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Another requirement is that clicking on any other name would make the previous content go away.. I'm not trying to hide/show here - I'd like to create a single ui-view that is targeted somehow but it may not be possible?

After much searching and reading tutorials I'm still at a loss as to how to accomplish this with Angular and/or ui-router.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could use `ng-show`directive on the `<div>` you need to show/hide and wrap Name with an element with an `on-click` directive that changes the visibility status

Comment: Thanks.   My question then is if a user clicks on each name in the list am I building up the DOM with a heavyweight chart and the JSON required to load it in memory?    My concern was if I'm not replacing the DOM view that eventually the browser would grind to a halt.   I was trying to use a single view ala ui-router named views if possible

Comment: use ng-if instead of ng-show if you do not want to load the graph when is "hidden"

Comment: yes I understand that but when I click another name i'm basically just hiding the already loaded graph instead of replacing it..  ideally there would be a way to replace the content when clicking on a name instead of building up the DOM with all these large objects.

Comment: if you use ng-if the element is removed from the DOM when ng-if evaluates to false. I wrote a quick  jsfiddle if can help is here https://jsfiddle.net/klode/m66tftoy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ng-if` directive on the `<div>` you need to show/hide and on `<span>{{name}}</span>` add an on-click directive that changes the visibility status. If you use `ng-if` the element is removed from the DOM when ng-if evaluates to false.

Here is an example [[demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/klode/m66tftoy/):

the template

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names">
        <span ng-click="togglePanel($index)">{{name}}</span>
        <div id='panel' ng-if='show[$index]'>Graph Here on click of name: {{graphData}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the controller:

```
var openId = null;
function closePanel(id) {
    $scope.show[id] = false;
    openId = null;
    $scope.graphData = null;
}
$scope.graphData;
$scope.show = {};
$scope.names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'];
$scope.togglePanel = function (id) {
    if (openId === id) {
        closePanel(openId);
        return;
    }
    if (openId !== null) {
        closePanel(openId);
    }
    $scope.show[id] = true;
    openId = id;
    $scope.graphData = loadData(id);
    //alert('load graph #' + (id+1));
}

function loadData(id) {
    return 'graph #' + (id + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks klode.   Exactly what I was needing to understand.